# Hive | ArrayIndexOutOfBounds | More than 1000 columns in select query

Tags: hadoop, indexoutofboundsexception, hiveql

I am trying to run some group operations (like max, min, avg, count etc) on Hive table with 300 columns. So, my select query would have more than 1000 columns and more than 4000 characters.
The select query is failing. I am facing the below issue.

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -128
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.closeOp(GroupByOperator.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:199)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -128
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.flush(GroupByOperator.java:1042)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.closeOp(GroupByOperator.java:1081)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -128
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator.processOp(ReduceSinkOperator.java:401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:1007)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.flush(GroupByOperator.java:1025)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -128
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.binarysortable.BinarySortableSerDe.serialize(BinarySortableSerDe.java:797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.binarysortable.BinarySortableSerDe.serialize(BinarySortableSerDe.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator.toHiveKey(ReduceSinkOperator.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ReduceSinkOperator.processOp(ReduceSinkOperator.java:394)
    ... 17 more
```

I get this error when I try to run the query on Hive terminal.

There is table in hive which contains 300 columns and when I perform group functions like count, min, max, distinct etc. on all the columns of this table, I face the above error. The hive query for this is huge and has 300*6 (let's consider 6 group functions - applied to each and every column) columns in it.

Comment: The number of columns shouldn't be an issue. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6381/limitations-on-of-hive-columns.html Seems like 15k columns is fine. You can try to reduce the number of columns and see if it works to help narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Hive version 1.1.0-cdh5.10.0. When the number of columns in select query (every select query has some group operation on it like max, min etc. ) are less than or equal to 1665, it works fine. If its more then its throws the above error. 
The number of columns in Hive table are less. It is when some statistics are calculated over it like min, max, count, null count etc, the number of columns in the select query increases by the factor of number of statistics (which are to be calculated for each column).